# XML Deserialization Diffrent Objects C#

Tags: c#, xml, object, tags, deserialization

maybe someone can give me a hint to handle a specific situation. I have an XML which i can not change which looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
<bde>
    <Host name="172.16.25" port="1234"/>
    <Datafile name="bde-%d-%s.txt"/>
    <Linien>
        <Linie id="2,3,4,6,7,10,12">
            <Parameter name="a"/>
            <Parameter name="b"/>
            <Parameter name="c"/>
            <Parameter name="d"/>
            <Parameter name="e"/>
            <Parameter name="f"/>
            <Parameter name="g"/>
            <Parameter name="h"/>
            <Parameter name="i"/>
            <Parameter name="j"/>
            <Parameter name="k"/>
            <Parameter name="l"/>
        </Linie>
        <Linie id="1,11">
            <Parameter name="a"/>
            <Parameter name="n"/>
        </Linie>
        <Linie id="5">
            <Parameter name="a"/>
            <Parameter name="b"/>
            <Parameter name="n"/>
            <Parameter name="ö"/>
            <Parameter name="z"/>
            <Parameter name="e"/>
            <Parameter name="r"/>
            <Parameter name="z"/>
        </Linie>
        <Linie id="8">
            <Parameter name="a"/>
        </Linie>
        <Linie id="9">
            <Parameter name="a"/>
            <Parameter name="p"/>
            <Parameter name="z"/>
            <Parameter name="y"/>
            <Parameter name="q"/>
            <Parameter name="oi"/>
            <Parameter name="c"/>
            <Parameter name="k"/>
            <Parameter name="b"/>
        </Linie>
    </Linien>
</bde>
```

And now i have to serialize the "Linien" into Objects but they have diffrent Parameter Counts.
Is it possible to read this XML like this in C#?

Best Regards,
Hendrik

Comment: Why don't you use List?

Comment: I tried but somehow my list stayed empty :( The thing is that i have for example linie 2 & 3& 4 & 5.. which all have to be the type of object :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace ConsoleApplication166
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BDE));
            BDE bde = (BDE)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("bde")]
    public class BDE
    {
        public Host Host { get; set; }
        public Datafile Datafile { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Linien")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Linie")]
        public List<Linie> Linie { get; set; }
    }
    public class Host
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string port { get; set; }
    }
    public class Datafile
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Linie
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }
    }
    public class Parameter
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

 
 
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to get all objects, THANKS A LOT, but what is missing now is the "ID"s so that for example bde with id 2,3,4,6,7 are type of bde[0]. The final result what i want to archive is, that the IDs (what are bde objects) are connected to all correct Parameters :)

Comment: Great, that helped me a Lot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to convert your XML into a C# data structure. If so, it is possible and there are libraries that can help you with this.

Personally, I would create a Linie and Linien class with the Linien class having a vector of Linie objects (so would support a different number of Linie per Linien object)